# Handler route in web.api

Tags: asp.net

I have web.api 2 project. I also tried to add handler to it. But every request (http://api.xxxx.xxx/handler) which I send return error of 404 code. I realized that problem is route config, but how I can fix it?

web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    <!-- ADD THIS -->
  </modules>  
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="ChatHandler" verb="*" path="/handler/" type="ProjectAPI.Handler.ChatHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Global.asax.cs

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("handler/{*path}");

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't changed the WebApiConfig routes, the default url should be:
http://api.xxxx.xxx/api/handler. I've never see a need to add this  to the configuration, why's that? Change only the configuration in the WebApiConfig.Register from ~/api/ to ~/ and it should work. Post some more code, because it's like "reading from the tea leaves" :)